# NestJS JwtService throws Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value (not due to env variables)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I need to use jwt in my project, so decided to go with: "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0"

In my shared module I am configuring the secret keys and have also ensured that the values are defined by logging them.
[image: Image showing shared module and terminal and how secret is loaded from env variables]

Below is the code for my user.service.ts where I am using my jwtService to sign the mobileNumber. Removed all mobileNumber verification steps for now just trying to debug jwtService.

[image]

I noticed that if I pass secret key to the sign function myself in jwt options, then it works fine. But then what was the use of configuring it in shared module where I passed the secret key and expired in time.

Also reading another answers on the internet I found that it is probably due to me adding JwtService in the providers array which probably creates a new instance of the JwtService,
[image: importing jwt service as provider in app.module.ts]

but if I don't do that I get this error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UserModule a valid NestJS module?
- If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
  })
```

```
async register(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const { mobileNumber } = createUserDto;
    return this.jwtService.sign(mobileNumber, {
      secret: 'testkajfkdf',
    });
  }
```

Please helppp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `JwtService` from the `providers` array of the `UserModule`, add the `JwtModule` to the `exports` of the `SharedModule`, and add the `SharedModule` to the `imports` of the `UserModule`

Comment: Thank you very much. Facepalm for forgetting to export JwtModule